# how to create a row for each datetime and each id?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**What Do I Have?**

I have 2 dates - `start_date` and `end_date` and a list of ids.

**What Do I Want?**

I want to create a `DataFrame` with a row for each datetime in interval of 15 minutes between
`start_date` and `end_date` and for each id in list of ids

I wrote the following function:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date, minutes, id_list):
    lst = []
    delta = timedelta(minutes=minutes)
    while start_date < end_date:
        lst.append(start_date)
        start_date += delta
        
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':lst})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': id_list})
    df_time = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','id'])
    prod = product(df1.values, df2.values)
    for index, i in enumerate(prod):
        df_time.loc[index] = [i[0][0], i[1][0]]
    
    return df_time
```

but my id list have more that 200 ids and the my dates are a whole year with 15 minutes interval, so its takes a lot of time to run. there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `pd.date_range(start, end, freq='15min')` . Can you add your expected output for some sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same function with the same signature:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date, minutes, id_list):
    dti = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=f'{minutes}T', closed='left')
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dti, id_list], names=['Time', 'id'])
    return idx.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
>>> daterange('2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', 360, [1, 2, 3])
                  Time  id
0  2021-01-06 00:00:00   1
1  2021-01-06 00:00:00   2
2  2021-01-06 00:00:00   3
3  2021-01-06 06:00:00   1
4  2021-01-06 06:00:00   2
5  2021-01-06 06:00:00   3
6  2021-01-06 12:00:00   1
7  2021-01-06 12:00:00   2
8  2021-01-06 12:00:00   3
9  2021-01-06 18:00:00   1
10 2021-01-06 18:00:00   2
11 2021-01-06 18:00:00   3
```